# Unable to fetch angular controller's data into HTML

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-components, angular-controller

I am using Angular 1.6.
I am trying to fetch x and y positions for an SVG element from a component controller.

```
this.painterModel = [];
var imageRef = {};
imageRef.path='assets/images/sample.png';
imageRef.xPos = 100;
imageRef.yPos = 100;
this.painterModel.push(imageRef);
```

Currently, the list has only one element. The HTML looks like this.

```
<svg id="frontView" width="1000" height="1000">
            <image ng-repeat="x in $ctrl.painterModel" href="x.path" x="x.xPos" y="x.yPos" />
</svg>
```

I always get this error in the console that says,

```
app.js:9756 Error: <image> attribute x: Expected length, "x.xPos".
app.js:9756 Error: <image> attribute y: Expected length, "x.yPos".
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

What about `{{ rendering }}` out the actual values instead?

```html
<image ng-repeat="x in $ctrl.painterModel" 
  ng-href="{{ x.path }}" 
  x="{{ x.xPos }}" 
  y="{{ x.yPos }}" 
/>
```

As it is now, you simply pass the string `'x.xPos'` to the attribute, not the value of `x.xPos`. Thats why you get the error *Expected length, "x.xPos"*. Also, use `ng-href` instead of `href`.